# Excel: Which row's sum equals to a number?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example I have this sheet:

[image]

I want to find the row that sum's equals to 10. I already tried MATCH with multiple criteria but it didn't work like I imagine.

For example first row's sum is: 14, second is 5, third is 0; while 4th is 10, so I want to get row 4.

I want to do it without adding another column/row

Comment: So what did you do with match because match(10,A1:A15,0) will find 10 in the range A1 to A15. Of course if it is not there them iferror will help : =IFERROR(MATCH(10,A1:A15,0),0).

Comment: Add a column with the SUM() of the numbers of interest, then match on that colum. Hide the column if you don't want it to appear

Comment: I think you didn't get my problem. For example first row's sum is: 14, second is 5, third is 0; while 4th is 10, so I want to get row 4.
I want to do it without adding another column/row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=MATCH(10,A1:A4+B1:B4+C1:C4+D1:D4+E1:E4,0)
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

EDIT:

Found a different array formula that uses full ranges:

```
=MATCH(10,MMULT(A1:E4,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:E4)^0)),0)
```

Again being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Can you do it with SUM for example? I mean if I have a lot of rows, then I don't have to type this formula for hours.

Comment: No, then you would want to use a helper column and put the sum in there and then match on that helper column

Comment: Great , Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Looks very great, but simple at the same time :D